# Creating a dictionary with a list of names

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this list of names: `[Frank, Sam, Kevin, Jack]`

Is it possible to create a dictionary using the names in the list to create something like this?

```
'Frank' : {'Sam': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Jack': 0},
 'Sam' : {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Jack': 0},
 'Kevin' : {'Frank': 0, 'Sam': 0, 'Jack': 0}
 'Jack' : {'Frank': 0, 'Sam': 0,  'Kevin': 0}
```

I want to know if it's possible to iterate through the list, pick the first name and then create a dictionary with it, with the other members in the list as keys and 0 as the default value. And then repeat it for the other elements in the list as well.

I was thinking of using something like this.

```
my_dynamic_vars = dict()
my_dynamic_vars.update({string: dict()})
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use nested [dictionary comprehensions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> lst = ['Frank', 'Sam', 'Kevin', 'Jack']
>>> dct = {x:{y:0 for y in lst if y != x} for x in lst}
>>> dct
{'Frank': {'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0, 'Jack': 0}, 'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0}, 'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0}, 'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0}}
>>>
>>> # Just to demonstrate
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dct)
{'Frank': {'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},
 'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},
 'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0},
 'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0}}
>>>
```

Comment: probably better than my answer :) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

ummm

```
d= {}
names = ["Frank","Sam","Kevin","Jack"]
for name in names:
    d[name] = dict.fromkeys(set(names).difference([name]),0)

print d
```

is probably how I would do it ..

Comment: `dict.fromkeys` not `dict().fromkeys`

Comment: yeah sorry :P it works either way(at least in 2.6) but yeah you are absolutely correct

Answer (score 1):

```
names = ['Frank', 'Sam', 'Kevin', 'Jack']
d = dict.fromkeys(names, 0)

names_dict = {}

for name in names:
    temp = d.copy()
    del temp[name]
    names_dict.update([(name, temp)])
```

**output:**

```
>>> for d in names_dict:
>>>     print d    
'Frank': {'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0}
'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0}
'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0}
'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0}
```

Comment: you could replace `dict.fromkeys([name], temp)` with `{name: temp}` Though OP asks about [the different output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22240166/4279)

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['Frank', 'Sam', 'Kevin', 'Jack']
d = {name: dict.fromkeys([x for x in names if x != name], 0)
     for name in names}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
```

#### Output

```
{'Frank': {'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},
 'Jack': {'Frank': 0, 'Kevin': 0, 'Sam': 0},
 'Kevin': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Sam': 0},
 'Sam': {'Frank': 0, 'Jack': 0, 'Kevin': 0}}
```